# Setting DateField Default value in Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer with datefield which needs to be set to a default date of three days from today. 
I'm unable to set it using "default" argument of the datefield in the serializer.
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do in normal way, So you need to write custom functions in models.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

def in_three_days():
    return timezone.now() + timedelta(days=3)

class TestModel(models.Model):
    event = models.DateTimeField(default=in_three_days)
```

Comment: Can this be done in DRF Serializer field as well? Like the Datefield in DRF?

Comment: Yeah you can do in serializer or views too

Comment: I'm unable to proceed. I'm writing the same function and passing a POST request but the data is not getting in request.data. It's showing blank.

Comment: tell me clealy what exactly you're trying

Comment: I have a Serializer with a DateField and I want a default value to be set when I pass a POST request but it is not happening.

Comment: Write the above function in models.py, in the request.data it is not mandatory to send the date field.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say this is your serializer:

```py
class User(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField()
```

There are 2 methods that you can use to give it a date as default:

### Method 1: Using Callable

This is a simple one that uses the datetime.today() method without parentheses

```py
class User(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField(default=datetime.today)
```

You can of course use your own callable like this:

```py
def three_days_from_now():
   return datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3)

class User(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField(default=three_days_from_now)
```

You can also make it simpler by using a `lambda` function:

```py
class User(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField(default=lambda: datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3)
```

You can even use a callable that gets the serializer itself as a parameter:

```py
class ThreeDaysFromNow:
    requires_context = True

    def __call__(self, serializer_field):
        # You can access the request for example:
        # request = serializer_field.context["request"]
        return datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3)

class User(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField(default=ThreeDaysFromNow())
```

### Method 2: Using the `__init__` function

```py
class User(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].default = datetime.toda() + timedelta(days=3)
```